# adding a variable to something like CCSprite

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

i have more than one enemy so i want to add a variable to the enemy sprites like for example

```
CCSprite *enemy;
enemy.direction = up;
```

how would i go about doing this?
easiest shortest fastest way possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in this way:

```
typedef enum
{
    kDirection_Up = 1000,
    kDirection_Down,
    kDirection_Left,
    kDirection_Right
}GMDirection;


@interface GMEnemy : CCSprite
{
    GMDirection direction;
}
```

//Usage:

```
GMEnemy *enemy = [GMEnemy spriteWithFile:@"Name.png"];
enemy.direction = kDirection_Up;
```

//check direct

```
if(enemy.direction == kDirection_Up)
```

Comment: where do i put the enum and interface code? thanks a lot by the way